# Complexification of $\mathfrak{so}(p,q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have that

> $\mathfrak{so}(p,q) = \{ A \in M_{p+q}(\mathbb{R}) : A^{T} I_{p,q} + I_{p,q} A = 0\}$.
>
> $\mathfrak{so}(p,q)_{\mathbb{C}} = \{ A \in M_{p+q}(\mathbb{C}) : A^{T} I_{p,q} + I_{p,q} A = 0\}$.
>
> $\mathfrak{so}(p+q) = \{ A \in M_{p+q}(\mathbb{C}) : A^{T} + A = 0\}$.
>
> I need to show that $\mathfrak{so}(p,q)_{\mathbb{C}} \cong \mathfrak{so}(p+q)$.

Here $I_{p,q} = \begin{bmatrix} I_{p} & 0 \\ 0 & -I_{q} \end{bmatrix}$. I was considering the map:

> $\phi : \mathfrak{so}(p,q)_{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \mathfrak{so}(p+q)$, $A \mapsto I_{p,q} A$

It is bijective but not a lie algebra homomorphism, is there another mapping I should consider?

Comment: Try $A\mapsto [I_{p,q}, A]$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's abbreviate $n:=p+q$. What you're using essentially is that over $\mathbb C$, the quadratic form defined by $I_{p,q}$ is congruent to the standard one defined by $I_{n}$. Find a base change matrix for that, i.e. $B \in GL_{n}(\mathbb C)$ such that $B^T \cdot I_{p,q} \cdot B = I_n$. (Hint: There will be imaginary entries, as the result we're getting at is not true over $\mathbb R$.) Then the same base change matrix will give an isomorphism of those Lie algebras, although now base change is of course given by $A \mapsto B^{-1} \cdot A \cdot B$.

To show this $f(A):= B^{-1}AB$ indeed induces an isomorphism of the Lie algebras as defined in the OP, follow the hint in the comment. If you fail to see it, here:

> $$A \in \mathfrak{so}(p,q)_{\mathbb C}$$
>  $$\Leftrightarrow A^{T} I_{p,q} + I_{p,q} A = 0$$
>  -- multiply both sides with $B^T$ from the left and $B$ from the right --
> $$ \Leftrightarrow B^T A^{T} I_{p,q}B + B^T I_{p,q} AB = 0$$
>  -- calling $B^{-T}$ the inverse of the transpose = transpose of the inverse, insert $I=B^{-T}B^T$ and $=BB^{-1}$ --
> $$\Leftrightarrow \underbrace{B^T A^{T} B^{-T}}_{f(A)^T} \underbrace{B^T I_{p,q}B}_{I_n} + \underbrace{B^T I_{p,q} B}_{I_n}\underbrace{B^{-1}AB}_{f(A)} = 0$$
>  $$\Leftrightarrow f(A) \in \mathfrak{so}(p+q)$$

Comment: The Idea I had was $B = \begin{bmatrix} I_{p} & 0 \\ 0 & iI_{q} \end{bmatrix}$, but why is $B^{-1} A B \in \mathfrak{so}(p+q)$, for $A \in \mathfrak{so}(p,q)$?

Comment: You want to get from $A^{T} I_{p,q} + I_{p,q} A = 0$ to $f(A)^T + f(A) = 0$, where $f(A):=B^{-1}AB$. Multiply both sides of the first line with something like $B$ and/or $B^T$ from the left and/or right, and fill in some $BB^{-1}$ and/or $B^TB^{-T}$ at appropriate places.