# Outer automorphism of the real Lie group $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is well-known that $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})=\mathrm{Spin}^+(3,1)$ is the double cover of the connected component containing the identity of the Lorentz group, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/669776/sl2-mathbbc-double-cover-of-so1-3. The group $\mathrm{Spin}^+(3,1)$ is contained in the Clifford algebra $\mathrm{Cliff}_{3,1}$. The Clifford algebra $\mathrm{Cliff}_{3,1}$ acts on the exterior algebra $\Lambda\mathbb{C}^2$, see section 3.2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.1556.pdf. This gives a complex 4-dimensional representation of $\mathrm{Spin}^+(3,1)$, called the spin representation of $\mathrm{Spin}^+(3,1)=\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

The outer automorphism of the real Lie group $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$ generated by the complex conjugation exchanging the two semi-spin representations of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

My question: How does the spin representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ decompose into the direct sum of two semi-spin representations and how does the complex conjugation exchange the two semi-spin representations of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, thus fix the spin representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$?

Thank you!

Comment: The outer automorphisms of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb C)$ are (a) trivial if we regard it as a complex Lie group, and (b) generated by complex conjugation if we regard it as a real Lie group. Remind us what it is exactly you're calling the spin representation of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb C)$. (Also, if you remember where you "heard" something, you should cite sources when possible.)

Comment: In fact, even when you look at the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ as a (six-dimensional) *real* Lie algebra (which one might want to clarify in notation, like $R_{\mathbb C \vert \mathbb R}$, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4177437/96384), then its Satake-Tits diagram is made up of two dots connected with an arrow, and its complexification is just two dots, which of course have a non-trivial diagram automorphism. In general, as soon as one looks at various *real* forms, questions like these become more intricate to answer than just looking at a Dynkin diagram.

Comment: In short, your first sentence is true a priori only for *complex semisimple* Lie algebras, and apparently your problem is not set in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I edited my question. Actually, I do not understand the spin representation.

Comment: Remind us what it is exactly you're calling the spin representation of ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb C)$.

Comment: @runway44 I added my understanding of the spin representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: ${\rm SL}(2,\Bbb C)$ is a set of matrices and ${\rm Spin}^+(3,1)$ is a subset of a Clifford algebra, so they're not *technically* equal as sets. Which means implicitly there is some way to reinterpret elements of one as elements of the other. How is this done? And how does the Clifford algebra $C\ell_{3,1}$ act on $\Lambda \Bbb C^2$?

Comment: The new question is answered on the Lie algebra level in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4389806/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4177437/96384, and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4026224/96384. Since the *real* $SL_2 (\mathbb C)$ is the simply connected Lie group over the algebra, its rep theory is virtually identical to the Lie algebra one. All irreps are given by pairs of $\ge 0$ integers $(m,n)$; complex conjugation flips the pair; the semi-spin ones must be $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$; the spin one is $(1,1)$ which, however, should be a tensor product (not sum) of the semi-spin ones.

Comment: Compare also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3738143/96384.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks for your comments! But I think that the spin representation is $(1,0)\oplus(0,1)$, not $(1,1)$ since the elements of a spin representation are called spinors and the Dirac spinor is the sum of two Weyl spinors. Also, $(1,1)$ is a vector representation, not a spinor spresentation.

Comment: Ah, of course, right. Then it makes sense it's a sum, and it makes sense that conjugation flips the summands hence stabilizes the whole thing.