# Are the two dimensional real representations of $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ quaternionic?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is clear from the symplectic group isomorphism $$SL(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong Sp(2, \mathbb{C}) $$
that there is an $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ invariant symplectic form on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

My question is whether or not this invariant form is enough to show the existence of an anti-linear $SL_2$ equivariant map, as it is in the compact case.

Another way to ask this, is whether or not the two irreducible 2d representations of the group are self-conjugate reps? I know for non-compact representations duality and conjugacy properties bifurcate.

EDIT: The answer to this  question is that the existance of an invariant form and the existance of an invariant anti-linear map, are only "the same fact" when the relevant group is compact.

Comment: Beyond Callum's answer, compare my answer to your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4389806/96384, as well as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4024163/96384 for background.

Comment: It seems my confusion arose in part from conflating, despite my best efforts, the roles of duality and conjugation. Thanks again Torsten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note importantly that reps being conjugate to each other and being quaternionic are features of real Lie algebras and their representations. However, $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ is famously isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ as a real Lie algebra so we can look at this in two ways.

As a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ has a single complex 2-dimensional rep which is naturally self-dual as the presence of an invariant bilinear form forces. There is no sense here in which we can talk about this rep being self-conjugate or quaternionic.

Meanwhile as a real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ has two complex 2-dimensional reps (the half-spin reps). They are each self-dual but they are conjugate to each other. As mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation#Real_representations), there is a Hermitian structure over the pair of them together (but not individually).

Comment: I think between Torsten & yourself my confusions have been cleared. I'd been holding on to compact intuitions from $SU(2)$ and being sloppy with complexifications. Can you confirm the following is correct here? 
For a real rep of a (generally non-compact) semi-simple Lie group, it is **self-duality** which dictates the **existence of** a G-invariant (symmetric/alternating) **bi-linear form**, and it is **self-conjugacy** which dictates the **existence of** a G-invariant **anti-linear map** (real/quaternionic structure). In the compact case, these facts imply one another.

Comment: Additionally, because I find it cool: when these are both satisfied, one finds a rep with an invariant Hermitian form, by composing the anti-linear map and bi-linear form.

Comment: @Craig Yes self-duality implies the existence of an invariant nondegenerate bilinear form which must be symmetric or alternating (the converse is also true). Self-conjugacy is equivalent to a real or quaternionic structure. When the dual is equal to the conjugate you get a Hermitian form (so self-dual plus self-conjugate falls into this category)